# Are my screws too deep in the OSB?

Tags: flooring, floor, subfloor, osb

Replacing rotted plywood with OSB - I fear I have made a grave error. The OSB is 23/32 (3/4 inch) and I have used the GRK #8 2inch screws to secure the OSB to the joists. I have sunk the screws about .25 - .5 inches into the OSB itself in most spots to try to get deeper into the joist. Is this too deep and should the screws be flush with the top of the OSB sheet? How much will this effect the integrity of the subfloor? Is it possible to just unscrew the screws back to the surface if necessary? Really do not want to have to replace the sheets.

First DIY project, didn't think about this until after the fact. All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you also use construction adhesive as is best practice?

Comment: OSB does not work in places plywood rots.  It's dry spaces only - the weather protection must be maintained tip-top.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, leave the screws alone. No worries and relax.
May I?

If the OSb has been covered with whatever, carpet or some other sheeting.  Just remove them, if not covered...  it is a home run for you.

Here it is.
The screws will not hurt the integerity of an entire sheet, no way, no how, no  problems.  That is right.  It hurts a spot in your mind only.

All you do is  simply drive new screws say 1" to 1 1/2" away from  each screws that you so much stressed about my friend.

Hell you can even take those rascal screws out and maybe you can give them a new home elsewhere.

They won't care either way.  I would just leave them in their comfort zone and no need to even cover the top of them with whatever putty or caulking. That is right.

Typically whatever things go on top of subflooring will either be some other form of sheeting or some sort of underlayment. This means you won't feel little spots from above walking on your floor.   I know what thought may arise in the mind.  Now that thought has been put to rest too.    And that is the full picture and the entire story.

[ Oh by the way, you go to hardware store and purchase drywall screw driver or some other form of driver that sets the screws just right for you, from 1/16-1/8 inch deep and become a happy camper.  They are cheap. this way you won't get all stressed about anything going too deep or not deep enough.
As then all you have to focus on is driving them screws. That is right.]

You are in good hands.

You take care.